# Where do I keep my pull buoy during a long open-water swim?

Tags: swimming

I am going to start to do long sea swimming to train for swim run races. I have the tools but I would like to know where I keep the pull buoy if I don't want to use it and if I want to use my legs normally.

I cannot actually keep it alongside the leg, like when running, because it compromises my body position. So where do I attach it? On the safety buoy behind me along with my stuff?

Does anyone have good advice based on experience?

Comment: I would clip it to the safety buoy.

Comment: As Jon said - attaching to the float will keep it out of the way of your arms and legs

Comment: Have you tried looking at YouTube?  This is the kind of stuff it excels at, besides cat vids.

Comment: In my opinion, pull buoys are meant for drills in the pool, not for open water. If you need the extra floatation that a pull buoys offers, maybe you need to try a wetsuit bottom for the open water training. Open water swims are a different animal from pool workouts, and you need your kick for lift, balance and speed.

Comment: I was tempted to say something similar, but then realised it was possible to read the question as about training swims in open water, when the pull buoy might be desirable, especially if pool access is problematic, or to train other aspect in a way that's more similar to the intended event